# new object every time a call a cloud function in nodeJS (with TypeScript)

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a cloud function whose object you can see here:
https://us-central1-mathfutures-cf044.cloudfunctions.net/simpleFunction

It should return a new object every time it is called. However, it does not. What is wrong?

Here is my cloud function:

```
export let simpleFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   buildQuestions();
   response.json(questions);
});

function s1plus1() {
  let number1 = myRandom(1);
  let number2 = myRandom(1);
  let problem;
  let qtype = "s1+1";
 
  problem = number1 + " + " + number2;
 
  let solution = number1 + number2;
 
  let exc = {
    qtype: qtype,
    question: problem,
    answer: solution,
  }
 
  return exc;
}

let numItems = 10;
let questions = [];
let i = 0;

function buildQuestions() {
  while (i < numItems) {
    questions.push(s1plus1());
    i = i + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this TypeScript? Then please [edit] and tag [tag:typescript].

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that numItems and i had to be initiated inside buildQuestions, like this:

```
let questions = [];

function buildQuestions() {
let numItems = 10;
let i = 0;
  while (i < numItems) {
    questions.push(s1plus1());
    i = i + 1;
  }
}
```